# Invertir filas a columnas en postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buenas tengo la siguiente consulta en donde muestro un grupo de dispositivos con la fecha y hora de emisión de cada uno necesito mostrar la fecha no como fila sino como columna agrupado por cada dispositivo

```
Name     | fecha1                | fecha2                | ....

FV_01    |  2019-07-23 04:59:32  |  2019-07-23 05:59:32  |   ....  
FV_02    |  2019-07-24 04:59:32  |  2019-07-24 05:59:32  |  ....
```

mi consulta es la siguiente y me da este resultado

```
select dev.name,pdt.gps_date_time  
from console.packet_data_tmp pdt 
inner join administration.device dev on pdt.unit_id=dev.imei

Name     | fecha

FV_01    |  2019-07-23 04:59:32
FV_02    |  2019-07-24 04:59:32
FV_01    |  2019-07-23 05:59:32
FV_02    |  2019-07-24 05:59:32
```

Comment: es difícil visualizar los códigos desde una captura de pantalla, puedes agregar dicho dataset como texto y darle formato igual que al código de tus consultas

Comment: Gracias ya edite la consulta

Comment: ¿Y cuantas `pdt.gps_date_time` por `dev.name` podría haber?

Comment: en el reporte que estoy intentando armar por lo menos serian 12 pdt.gps_date_time

Answer (score 0):

Pasar de una vista "vertical" a una "horizontal" (transposición) es posible, pero lamentablemente tiene limitaciones, por empezar el crecimiento "horizontal" siempre tiene un límite, no se puede crecer a lo ancho de manera indefinida, luego, es necesario y mandatorio saber y restringir de antemano el número de columnas a mostrar, tanto con la solución simple que te voy a proponer como con el uso de [`crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html) necesitas establecer el límite de columnas horizontales en la propia consulta.

Una forma bien sencilla, es "numerar" las fechas según su orden cronológico, para luego en una subconsulta ir asignando cada fecha a una columna en particular. La idea conceptual, considerando las 12 columnas sería algo así:

```
select  name,
        max(case when rn = 1  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha1',
        max(case when rn = 2  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha2',
        max(case when rn = 3  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha3',
        max(case when rn = 4  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha4',
        max(case when rn = 5  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha5',
        max(case when rn = 6  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha6',
        max(case when rn = 7  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha7',
        max(case when rn = 8  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha8',
        max(case when rn = 9  then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha9',
        max(case when rn = 10 then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha10',
        max(case when rn = 11 then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha11',
        max(case when rn = 12 then gps_date_time else null end)  as 'Fecha12'
        from (select    dev.name,
                        pdt.gps_date_time,
                        row_number() over (partition by dev.name order by pdt.gps_date_time) as 'rn'  
                        from console.packet_data_tmp pdt 
                        inner join administration.device dev 
                            on pdt.unit_id=dev.imei
        ) t
        group by name
```

Con [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) generamos un numerador único para cada `dev.name` (`partition by`) y en el orden cronológico (`order by`). Luego tomamos esto como subconsulta y agrupamos por `dev.name` y según el número de cada fecha, ubicamos la misma en su columna correspondiente con una función de agregación.